# UPDATE query php syntax

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to do a UPDATE query in php and I get a syntax error

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id
>   = '30'' at line 1

```
 $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET nombre WHERE id = '$id_usuario'";
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    if ($result) {
        echo "Ok";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    die;
}
```

the error is in the $sql = ... line.
Thanks!

Comment: Your error does not belong with this query. The query you show is searching for `email`, while your error says it's searching for `id`. Unless $email contains `something' WHERE id = '30`, in which case you really ought to be using prepared statements and parameter binding.

Comment: or do you have a trigger in your db?

Comment: @aynber yes, sorry xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UPDATE usuario SET nombre WHERE id = '$id_usuario'

You didn't provide a new value to update. Your query should look like:

```
UPDATE usuario SET nombre = :new_name WHERE id = :id_usuario
```

Comment: Ok...just a neglect...

Comment: This is wide open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: this is not the way using prepared statements same in question @Chariot See here for proper prepared statements in pdo or MySQL I  : https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared